# Using setControl in nested reactive form

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular-reactive-forms, angular2-formbuilder

I would like to know what I have to do to use the "setControl" and "get" in a reactive form when I have an array inside of another formBuilder group. For instance:

```
this.formulario = this.formBuilder.group({
  title: [this.racPessoa.title, [Validators.required]],
  description: [this.racPessoa.description, [Validators.required]],
  person: this.formBuilder.group({
    idPerson:[this.racPessoa.person.idPerson],
    name:[this.racPessoa.person.nome],
    personDocument: this.formBuilder.array([])
  }),
});
```

In the case above, if I want to handle with the "title, I can write:

```
this.formulario.setControl('title', something);
this.formulario.get('title');
```

But I don't know how to write both sentences above when I want to handle with the "personDocument", which is inside of a person

I've tried to use:

```
this.formulario.setControl('person.personDocument', something);
this.formulario.get('person.personDocument')
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Any reason why you want to use setControl?

Comment: I'm using setcontrol and getcontrol to add/remove field of this array

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`FormGroup`'s `setControl` method doesn't support for nested form control structures, it will just detect and set form control at current layer, see **[setControl](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/6.0.3/packages/forms/src/model.ts#L1034)** and **[registerControl](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/6.0.3/packages/forms/src/model.ts#L1005)**.

For your case, `this.formulario.setControl('person.personDocument', something);` will just add new form control(*key of `person.personDocument`*) to the your current layer(you can confirm at your formGroup's controls).

```
this.formulario = this.formBuilder.group({
  title: [this.racPessoa.title, [Validators.required]],
  description: [this.racPessoa.description, [Validators.required]],
  person: this.formBuilder.group({
    idPerson:[this.racPessoa.person.idPerson],
    name:[this.racPessoa.person.nome],
    personDocument: this.formBuilder.array([])
  }),
  'person.personDocument': something     // newly added form control
});
```

So you will need to add form control at the exact layer, for example:

```
(this.formulario.get('person') as FormGroup).setControl('personDocument', new FormControl('aaa'));
```

Comment: Please, resolve your typo. The example should use `this.formulario` instead of `this.form` to be in consens with the rest of your answer. Thanks for the help.