# Reactive forms angular adding new controls

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying to add new form controls on form from array, but i have problem that i have always empty control, even if i have some values in array

This is what i have for now

```
 this.userVehicles= [];
 this.userVehicles= [{Model: 'Fiat', RegistrationPlate: 'Taxi', LastServiceDate: 'Nov 11', Vin: '111', YearManufacture: '2015'}];

const vehicleFGs: any = this.userVehicles.map(vehicle => this._fb.group({
      Model: [vehicle.model],
      RegistrationPlate: [vehicle.registrationPlate],
      LastServiceDate: [vehicle.lastServiceDate],
      Vin: [vehicle.vin],
      YearManufacture: [vehicle.yearManufacture],
    }));


    const vehicleFormArray: FormArray = this._fb.array(vehicleFGs);
    ((this.myAccountForm as FormGroup).get('Owner') as FormGroup).setControl('Vehicles', vehicleFormArray);
```

The problem i think i have is in this line
**`((this.myAccountForm as FormGroup).get('Owner') as FormGroup).setControl('Vehicles', vehicleFormArray);`**

I think i dont bind controls properly, any idea?

Comment: You might take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50520278/using-setcontrol-in-nested-reactive-form in regards to `.setControl()`

Comment: Can you write a answer?

Comment: Let me see what I can do

Comment: You should be able to use `.addControl()` instead of  `.setControl()`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `.setControl()`, use `.addControl()`:

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
  owner: this.formBuilder.group({}),
});

const vehicleFormGroups: FormGroup[] = this.vehicles.map(v => {
  return this.formBuilder.group({
    model: [
      v.Model,
    ],
    registrationPlate: [
      v.RegistrationPlate,
    ],
    lastServiceData: [
      v.LastServiceDate,
    ],
    vin: [
      v.Vin,
    ],
    yearManufacture: [
      v.YearManufacture,
    ],
  });
});

const vehiclesFormArray: FormArray = new FormArray(vehicleFormGroups);

(this.form.get('owner') as FormGroup).addControl('vehicles', vehiclesFormArray);
```

Comment: I'll try to get a Stack Blitz going as an example. This code is working for me in my local dev environment.

Comment: You can view the console output at: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-array-example2 to see a working example.